# Power BI Total Marks for Each Item

Tags: powerbi

i have a table in power BI that looks like below

[image]

The table shows performance(total_marks) for each facility for a certain indicator_id. I need a table that summarizes like this by adding the MARKS_OVERALL column at the end that will show the total_marks for each facility.

[image]

Please i need assist from you guys, how can i achieve this

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, i have been able to solve it usin this
=CALCULATE(SUM(Table6[total_marks]),ALLEXCEPT(Table6,Table6[facility]))